# Is it benefit to create a index key if unique key already exists on the same columns?

Tags: mysql, index, unique-constraint

The table schema for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bar2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uqx_bar1_bar2` (`bar1`,`bar2`),
  KEY `idx_bar1` (`bar1`),
  KEY `idx_bar2` (`bar2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bar1` FOREIGN KEY (`bar1`) REFERENCES `bars1` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bar2` FOREIGN KEY (`bar2`) REFERENCES `bars2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This table is created for m:n relations, index key is created separately for `bar1` and `bar2`, and unique key is created for both columns `bar1` and `bar2`.

In most cases, this query will be executed:

```
SELECT * FROM foos WHERE bar1=? AND bar2=?
```

The **question** is: Will query optimizer get benefit if index key created for both columns `bar1` and `bar2`? That is:

```
ALTER TABLE foos ADD INDEX `idx_bar1_bar2` (`bar`,`bar2`)
```

Comment: You already have it: `UNIQUE KEY uqx_bar1_bar2 (bar1,bar2)`. Even `KEY idx_bar1 (bar1)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More discussion on building indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Furthermore your table smells like a many:many mapping table??  Here are several tips on efficiency for such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

> There is already using primary key i.e, clustered Index and then used UNIQUE KEY on `uqx_bar1_bar2` (`bar1`,`bar2`). So there is no more needed KEY `idx_bar1` (`bar1`),  KEY `idx_bar2` (`bar2`).

Comment: Not quite right -- `(bar1, bar2)` does _not_ help if you need `(bar2)`; only leftmost works.